# How does one transfer money quickly to a broker like Ameritrade over the weekend? (If money is no object) Would a wire transfer work?

Tags: united-states, stocks, brokerage, td-ameritrade

I'm trying to transfer funds to my Ameritrade account before extended hours tomorrow.

Comment: Gamestonk.....? yeah wire is the quickest.

Comment: You know it. What company do you use to wire? And what settings?

Comment: The bank wires it for you.  Get TD Ameritrade's wire information, and give your bank the information.  It you might even be able to initiate it from your bank's web site.  Over the weekend, though?  No.

Comment: Other than depositing cash at a local TD branch tomorrow morning, there's no way anything else will clear by then.  Time to crack open the mattress?

Comment: it's totally impossible while banks are closed

Comment: This sounds like the start of a very bad reactionary investment plan. Whatever you are trying to do that urgently in the stock market, just don't. It won't end well.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you already have a relationship with TD Ameritrade, then it all likelihood, your transfer will be subject to review and won't be available for trading premarket futures on Monday. Your personal bank might want to review your transfer to, especially if you don't have a history of moving large sums of money around.

Comment: The broker is quite irrelevant here - the problem is that the money is held in banks and even while a swift telex avis transfer can be credited in 20 minutes - banks must be open for this.